# creating a menu after a long click event on a list view

Tags: android, listview, menu, long-click

I have a list view connected to a database, showing a all the entries. I want a menu to show up if the user long clicks a item in the listview(database entry), showing options to edit or delete the entry. how can i do this.

Till now, I have tried using a onItemLongClick listener and a toast in it showing the id of the view long clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    String res = Long.toString(id);
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of using `onItemLongClick` you can use

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, 
                    final View v, final ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 ...
}
```

where you setup the options for edit and delete or whatever you need to.

The actions for the item selected from the context menu can be processed in

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item)
```

For more information on context menu see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html).

For a step by step tutorial visit [here](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/).

> Edit
> The second link is broken as it was quite old.
> But I guess you can refer one of the other highly voted answer to see all the steps involved,

Comment: I tried using oncreateContextMenu, and it is working for me till now..
Thank You

Comment: It was quite old. Was working when I had put it. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 119):

First you need to register your context menu on list view.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

Then, just override activity methods.

```
/**
 * MENU
 */

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      if (v.getId()==R.id.list_view) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
      }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.add:
         // add stuff here
            return true;
          case R.id.edit:
            // edit stuff here
                return true;
          case R.id.delete:
        // remove stuff here
                return true;
          default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
}
```

Here is an example of menu_list.xml file (you have to put the file in the res/menu folder).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:id="@+id/add"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
              android:title="@string/menu_add" />

      <item android:id="@+id/edit"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
              android:title="@string/menu_edit" />

       <item android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/my_icon_delete"
             android:title="@string/menu_delete" />

</menu>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how do I know which item in the list was longclicked ? Any ID?

Comment: OK, I found it. You can get ID or POSITION of the list item which was longclicked like this:

`((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).id`
`((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).position`

Comment: switch statement no longer works as values such as R.id.add are no longer generated as constants. Hence I needed to replace switch with if-else stmt!

Comment: Great example but icons are not supported in context menus

Comment: Hey, you did set up icons for menu, but there are no icons in menu. Why? How I can show icons?

Comment: I tried in in my dialogfragment, context menus were shown but `onContextItemSelected` not being called after click on menu item. Why? I use Android 6.0

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

```
//Deleted individual cart items
    //on list view cell long press
    cartItemList.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
              final CharSequence[] items = { "Delete" };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                builder.setTitle("Action:");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        cart = cartList.get(position);
                        db.removeProductFromCart(context, cart);

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.success))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.item_removed))
                        .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CartDetailsActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                         })
                         .show();

                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            //do your stuff here
              return false;
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Activity.openOptionsMenu()` in your click item method

check here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29

Comment: If you can use the options menu - this a nice solution (1 line!) and alternative to doing all the setup needed for a contextMenu off the activity

Answer (score 1):

**

> after register your context menu on list view

**
override onCreateContextMenu Method like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.listView){
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            MenuItem mnu1=menu.add(0,0,0,"Delete");
            MenuItem mnu2=menu.add(0,1,1,"Share");
        }
    }
```

then coding for each item that can be selected

```
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuItem.getMenuInfo();
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Delete Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Share Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use registerForContextMenu(); to link context menu to any View successor.

To access to selected ListItem data, simple use the AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.
E.g.:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    long selectid = menuinfo.id; //_id from database in this case
    int selectpos = menuinfo.position; //position in the adapter
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        doSomething(selectid);
    break;
    case 2:
        doSomethingElse(selectpos);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick note for those still struggling, there're two methods

```
registerForContextMenu(list);
unregisterForContextMenu(list);
```

Make sure you pick the first.