# How to add menu to Android List item via long click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm attempting to add a menu to a list view. When the user long click's on a list item I want to have that menu populate (really I'm showing a list of items the user wants to buy, and the menu will only display "Remove")... This is how i'm displaying the list, how would I add the the listenener for the long click?

```
public static class CheckoutFragment extends ListFragment {
    /**
     * 
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public List<Entry> cart;
    JSONObject json;
    jsonParser jParser = new jsonParser();
    JSONArray directory;

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static Fragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        CheckoutFragment fragment = new CheckoutFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public CheckoutFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        cart = Dashboard.datasource.getAllProducts();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkout, container,
                false);
        Button order = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.order);
        order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Order Submitted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                submitOrder();
                flag = false;

            }
        });

        CheckoutArrayAdapter checkoutAdapter = new CheckoutArrayAdapter(
                container.getContext(), R.layout.fragment_checkout,
                R.layout.checkout_list_item, cart);
        setListAdapter(checkoutAdapter);



        Dashboard.datasource = DisplayProduct.datasource;

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                return false;
                // Show menu for item in position.
            }
        });

        return v;


    }

    protected void submitOrder() {

        OrderTask order = new OrderTask();
        order.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((Dashboard) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }

    public class CheckoutArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private List<Entry> cart;

        public CheckoutArrayAdapter(Context context, int listViewLayout,
                int listItemLayout, List<Entry> cartItems) {
            super(context, listViewLayout, listItemLayout, cartItems);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            cart = cartItems;
        }

        /**
         * Populate new items in the list.
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkout_list_item,
                        parent, false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }
            Entry item = getItem(position);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_entry)).setText(item
                    .getQty()
                    + "x  "
                    + item.getName()
                    + "\t"
                    + item.getSku() + " ");



            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the ListView's [`setOnItemLongClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29). Like this:

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        // Show menu for item in position.
    }
});
```

At the end of `onViewCreated()` would be the appropriate time to execute this code, i.e.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

06-09 15:37:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(18980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 15:37:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(18980): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
06-09 15:37:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(18980):  at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:386)
06-09 15:37:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(18980):  at android.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:280)
06-09 15:37:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(18980):  at com.bluelabelhosting.android.vendturevending.Dashboard$CheckoutFragment.onCreateView(Dashboard.java:342)

Code is updated.

Comment: @user1890328 Sorry, you're right. Override `onViewCreated()` instead. Edited answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial for Long Press Context Menu: http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/

There is a similar question: [creating a menu after a long click event on a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207366/creating-a-menu-after-a-long-click-event-on-a-list-view)

Here is a code for longpress action for any row of your liistview

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
   long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return false;
   }
});
```