# Contextual ActionBar not showing on ListView with EditTexts

Tags: android, focus, contextual-action-bar

My ListView contains an EditText as part of each row and CAB won't show up when I long press a row.

It does show up if I:

- change the EditText to TextView
- or set `focusable="false"` in the EditText
- or set `descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the parent view (a LinearLayout)

It didn't help to:

- set `descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` (or after) in the parent view.

How can I have CAB and a working EditText at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

CAB on long press isn't default behavior.

Have you tried registering the list for the context menu?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17207576/850734